# TeamCity not showing service messages with powershell

Tags: powershell, teamcity, psake

I'm running a project configuration using powershell/psake and I'm using the TeamCity powershell module (https://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake-contrib/wiki/teamcity.psm1) yet TeamCity only shows the configuration as "Running"

[image]

However, the build log clearly displays all of the service messages:

```
[15:41:34]WARNING: Some imported command names include unapproved verbs which might make 
[15:41:34]them less discoverable.  Use the Verbose parameter for more detail or type 
[15:41:34]Get-Verb to see the list of approved verbs.
[15:41:34]##teamcity[progessMessage 'Running task Clean']
[15:41:34]Executing Clean
[15:41:34]running the build
[15:41:34]##teamcity[progessMessage 'Running task Build']
[15:41:34]Executing Build
```

Am I wrong to thing these should be showing up in the project status instead of just "Running"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is typo in generated message. I just created pull request with fix. https://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake-contrib/pull/1

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that...the shame!

Comment: I had the same problem 2 years ago, but I fixed only one message and there were two messages with the same typo. So it was easy for me to find it now. :)